# Sitemap - O que listar?

Tags: seo

Estou criando o sitemap do meu projeto e ao listar o link http://www.site.com.br/artigos lembrei-me que cada artigo tem uma pagina única, sendo assim uma pagina dinâmica.
A duvida que veio a mente foi a seguinte: Eu devo listar a pagina de artigo único? Ou a de cada artigo? Se sim, como farei isso, porque o site possui mais de 100 artigos, entao teria de listar um por um?..

Comment: Caso esteja usando asp.net pode usar https://www.nuget.org/packages/EasySiteMap/

Comment: @Ricardo Excelente :) +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim você terá que listar todas, mas geralmente os sitemaps em xml são apenas para facilitar o buscador, então não precisaria listar todas obrigatoriamente, poderia listar os artigos principais ou páginas principais (que levam a conteúdos diferentes), mas o mais importante é listar páginas que não tem linkagem direta. No entanto o que você vai listar pode ser algo bastante relativo a cada caso.

Pra resumir os sitemaps servem para facilitar a indexação e apenas isto, não quer dizer que ele será o único caminho que você poderá usar para indexar.

### Preciso listar manualmente

Claro que não (acaso esta seja a sua duvida), você parece usar o PHP, no caso pode usar o PHP e o banco aonde estão as urls para gerar o seu xml, talvez semanalmente.

No entanto também existem scripts prontos para isto:

> Note que eles estão um pouco desatualizados

- https://github.com/o/sitemap-php
- https://github.com/jdevalk/XML-Sitemap-PHP-Script
- https://github.com/RudyJessop/Sitemap-Generator (gera automaticamente)

Se estiver usando wordpress:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/

Comment: Excelente resposta @GuilhermeNascimento, apenas complementando, é sempre bom não indexar páginas como categorias ou tags, pois elas alteram com frequência, criando links que não correspondem necessariamente ao conteúdo e gerando uma taxa de saída muito maior do site. Ví essas recomendações no plugin "WordPress SEO" e achei importante ressaltar isso para o autor da pergunta.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri na verdade eu não tinha consciência disto, vou editar, obrigado é sempre bom aprender :D - Não adicionei o seu comentário a resposta pois o seu comentário é esclarecedor e mérito seu, mas removi o trecho da resposta que falava pra indexar as categorias.